# i want to stop iMessages from being deleted

Tags: mac

I want to prevent my step daughter deleting message from iMessages so they can't be viewed (once you delete that using the more button you can't see it again)

Is there a way to prevent that (disable that function)?

Comment: While you have been given a method that will work to read messages, you should by all means include a mental health professional in your discussions, because nothing that's here helps build a healthy trusting relationship.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to disable that function.
But you always can get another Apple device, such as mac or any of iOS family and login with her apple ID in iMessage section of settings.
Once you'll made it that will allow you get the copy of all the iMessage conversations.
Despite the reason of your idea, I just want mark it as not so fair activity. Check twice if you will be charged for that by the law of your country.

Comment: a + for check twice for the law :)

Comment: Messages are only stored for seven days, and only if multiple devices are set up at the time the message is sent, so any past conversations would not be accessible using this technique.

Comment: Also keep in mind that this is quite annoying for people sending your daughter messages and might impact reliability of her iMessage account as the messages are considered "delivered" even though they are not accessible to her if only your device received them.